# "We are going inside to the someone's heart" vs "We are going into someone's heart"

Tags: prepositions, style

When we love someone, what's more appropriate for use? "we are going **inside** her heart" or "We are going **into** her heart"?

Comment: Neither.  They sound like heart surgery, not being in love.

Answer (score 3):

> When we love someone, what's more appropriate for use? "we are going inside her heart" or "We are going into her heart"

In English one usually "gets" to someone in the sense of emotion. "To get" suggests more accomplishment than simply "to go".  "To go" suggests a simple move, and emotions are usually not so simple.

> We are "*getting* in her heart", or "*getting* into her heart"

is much better than "going".

> "We are *gaining* her heart" or "We are *winning* her heart"

would be even better.